# ReactJS: why is pushing value into this.state array causing type error?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I tried to push a value into a state array but I get an issue TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined at this.state.rows.push(a);

Know why? I am trying to push a new value into the array after i click a button.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      rows: ['hello',<p>gfdfg</p>,'mello']
    }

  }

  handle(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var a = "h";
    this.state.rows.push(a);
    alert("hello");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        Button<br/>
        <input type="submit" id="black" onClick={this.handle}/><br/>
        <p>{this.state.rows}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: mutating state is definitely not a good idea instead of pushing how about using `this.setState({  })` instead of `this.state.rows.push(a);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of things that are wrong here:

1. you should NEVER change the state directly:

This is a big No No:

`this.state.rows.push(a);`

instead you should do something like this:

 `this.setState({ rows : [...this.state.rows, a] })`

or without ES6:

```js
const newArray = this.state.rows.slice();
newArray.push(a);
this.setState({ rows: newArray })
```

You should always replace the state with a new one.

2. `this` in a react component is not what you think it is, in order to make it work you can do one of two things:

a. change your method to an arrow function:

```js
handle = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var a = "h";
    this.state.rows.push(a);
    alert("hello");
  }
```

b. bind `this` to the method:

```js
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      rows: ['hello',<p>gfdfg</p>,'mello']
    }
    
    this.handle = this.handle.bind(this);

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

the method `handle` does not have access to the context of the class i.e `this`; consider writing it as a fat arrow function

```
// class definition 
handle = () => {
  e.preventDefault();
  var a = "h";
  this.state.rows.push(a);
  alert("hello");
}

render() {
  // render logic
}
```

Having said this, mutating the state is not a good idea, consider using `setState` if you want your component to re-render as a result of state change

```
handle = () => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let { rows } = this.state;
  var a = "h";
  rows.push(a);
  this.setState({
    rows,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing wrong, you have to use setState() method to push the value in the array:

```
handle = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var a = "h";
    let tempRows = [...this.state.rows];
    tempRows.push(a)
    this.setState({rows:tempRows})
    alert("hello");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

1. Event handlers require 'this' to be bound: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html So following this, you must either write: `this.handle = this.handle.bind(this)` in your contructor, or change handler to arrow function, if your build process supports transpilation of class fields.
2. React component will only update if component props change, or **component state changes**. Which is done by comparing **references**. In your case, when you push to the array, you are mutating the state, so the new reference is never created, and component does not re-render. If you want to verify that, just put `console.log(this.state.rows)` below `this.state.rows.push(a)` and you'll see that the array has received the new value, but component does not represent it. You need to use `this.setState` to create a new reference for your state, like so: `this.setState({ rows: [...this.state.rows, a] })`

Answer (score 0):

Another way of returning a new array from the current array with additional elements and then pushing to state is to use the concat method.

Example :

```
this.setState({ users: this.state.users.concat(<Additonal Items Here>)}
```