# Add an object with setState() to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

My component's state is an array of objects:

```
this.state = {
  userFavorites: [{id: 1, title: 'A'}, {id: 2, title: 'B'}]
}
```

I need to, everytime I click in a button, update my state with another object like the ones I have in my state above; for example: {id: 3, title: 'C'}.

If I simply concat them and set the state, the last object keeps being changed by the one that's being added.

Do I need the spread operator here?

Comment: Why cant you simply use `push`?

Comment: Since you're pushing object, you can use spread operator while concatenating. Please don't use push.

Comment: @vijaykrishna why push cannot be used?

Comment: newList = [...this.state.user favourites, { id:3, title: 'C' }]

Comment: @brk [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369357/reactjs-why-is-pushing-value-into-this-state-array-causing-type-error) might help you

Comment: @brk because it will mutate the state

Comment: How did you “simply concat them and set the state”? That sounds right.

Answer (score 6):

You should do it this way. Below is the most recommended way to push values or objects to an array in react

```
 this.setState( prevState => ({
     userFavorites: [...prevState.userFavourites,  {id: 3, title: 'C'}]
 }));
```

To push to the beginning of the array do it this way

```
   this.setState( prevState => ({
     userFavorites: [{id: 3, title: 'C'}, ...prevState.userFavourites]
  }));
```

Comment: reverse the order--the OP wants the new object added to the _beginning_ of the array, not the end

Answer (score 4):

for functional component

```
const [userFavorites, setUserFavorites] = useState([]);

setUserFavorites((prev) => [...prev, {id: 3, title: 'C'}])
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do this. The simplest way for what you are needing to do is to use the spread operator. Note that item is the object being added to userFavorites.

```
this.setState({
  userFavorites: [ ...this.state.userFavorites, item ],
});
```

Note: If at some point down the line you are needing to update a specific item in the array, you could use the update function from the immutability-helpers library. https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html

Comment: Thank you. This response was immensely helpful. I have been pulling my hair out with the .map() is not a function error.  I was obviously pushing incorrectly to the array of objects in state, and which was having a domino effect on the rest of my app. The spread operator was the key.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
const userFavorites = [...this.state.userFavorites, {id: 3, title: 'C'}]
this.setState({ userFavorites })
```

Comment: It keeps being changed by the one that's being added. Not sure if there's some kind of issue with my implementation but this is getting weird.