# how to add element in an array in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I get the error: `this.state.questions[key] is not iterable`
I want to push `optiontext` from input field to `options` array

```js
this.state = {
  sections: [{
    key: 1,
    value: 1
  }],
  optionText: '',
  questions: [{
    id: Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000000000000),
    query: '',
    sectionId: 1,
    selectedType: 1,
    options: ['1st option', ],
    isChecked: true
  }],
}
addOption = (key) => {
  const addtext = this.state.optionText //typed text in input 
  let option = this.state.questions[key].options; //trying to access array in array of object 
  this.setState({
    questions: [...this.state.questions[key], addtext]
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```
  sections: [{ key: 1, value: 1 }],
  optionText: '',
      surveyTitle: '',
      description: '',
      questions: [{
        id: Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000000000000),
        query: '',
        sectionId: 1,
        selectedType: 1,
        options: ['1st option',],
        isChecked: true
      }],
    }
 addOption = (key) => {
    const addtext = this.state.optionText //typed text in input 
    let option = this.state.questions[key].options; //trying to access array in array of object 
    this.setState({ questions: [...this.state.questions[key], addtext] });
  }
```

Comment: totally new to this world :)

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52954908/add-an-object-with-setstate-to-an-array-of-objects

Comment: describe the problem.  your expected input and output.  This question should be useful for future readers who are searching for similar problems, and should be in a format that a person with no prior knowledge of your code can read and understand the problem you are having.

Comment: 'this.state.questions[key] is not iterable'

i want to push optiontext from input field to options array

Comment: You probably want to add an option to the `questions` array using the [`push()` prototype method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). It would be good practice to explore the other prototype methods shown on this page.

Comment: i want push it inside options array inside of questions array

Comment: questions[key] is an object, not an array.  Hence the spread operation is failing to iterate over it.  Assuming of course that "key" is a valid index of the array and it is not returning undefined

Comment: key is valid its returning 0 as expected

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi i need to push inside array inside an array of objects 
that post is just simple array of objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

extract option and append a value.  Clone questions before splicing in new question with merged options.  Update state.

```js
this.state = {
  sections: [{
    key: 1,
    value: 1
  }],
  optionText: '',
  questions: [{
    id: Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000000000000),
    query: '',
    sectionId: 1,
    selectedType: 1,
    options: ['1st option', ],
    isChecked: true
  }],
}
addOption = (key) => {
  const addtext = this.state.optionText //typed text in input 
  let options = this.state.questions[key].options; //trying to access array in array of object 
  options = [...options, addText];
  const questions = [...this.state.questions];
  questions.splice(key, 1, {...questions[key], options});

  this.setState({
    questions
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```